# How to test Devise Async with Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rspec-rails, sidekiq, devise-async

Thanks in advance!
Sidekiq is working just fine, but I cannot manage to test it with Devise Async, or should I say that I cannot test the latter?

According to Sidekiq's documentation, when test mode is set to fake!, any job given to a worker is pushed to an array named `jobs` of that same worker. So it is trivial to test the increase of this array.

But, with Devise Async, it is not so trivial, although its backend includes `Sidekiq::Worker`. Here's a small list of things that I tried to test:

- `Devise::Async::Backend::Sidekiq.jobs`
- `Devise::Mailer.deliveries`
- `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries`
- `Devise::Async::Backend::Worker.jobs`

None of these testing subjects points an increase in size. Since Devise sends its emails as models callbacks, I tried testing both in a model and in a controller spec. Using Factory Girl and Database Cleaner, I also tried both modes: transaction and truncation. Needless to say that I also tried both modes of Sidekiq: fake! and inline!.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing#testing-delay-and-delay_for-methods), you can check the queue size as

```
Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedMailer.jobs.size
```

Comment: ActionMailer::Base.deliveries are being [] when i am using sidekiq ? any configuration do we need to do for that

Answer (score 0):

Was working on this issue, chanced upon a beautiful implementation done by gitlab which I thought might be helpful in testing devise-async or email that are push via the sidekiq queue.
[spec_helper.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb) 
[email_helpers.rb](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/spec/support/email_helpers.rb)

By adding these lines in `spec_helper.rb`

```
# An inline mode that runs the job immediately instead of enqueuing it
require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include EmailHelpers
  # other configurations line
end
```

And adding `/spec/support/email_helpers.rb`

```
module EmailHelpers
  def sent_to_user?(user)
    ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.map(&:to).flatten.count(user.email) == 1
  end

  def should_email(user)
    expect(sent_to_user?(user)).to be_truthy
  end

  def should_not_email(user)
    expect(sent_to_user?(user)).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

To run the test for example testing your forgot password, I am assuming you know rspec, factorygirl, capybara
 `/spec/features/password_reset_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Password reset', js: true do
  describe 'sending' do
    it 'reset instructions' do
      #FactoryGirl create
      user = create(:user)
      forgot_password(user)

      expect(current_path).to eq(root_path)
      expect(page).to have_content('You will receive an email in a few minutes')
      should_email(user)
    end
  end

  def forgot_password(user)
    visit '/user/login'
    click_on 'Forgot password?'
    fill_in 'user[email]', with: user.email
    click_on 'Reset my password'
    user.reload
  end
end
```

You would notice that in this test implementation

1. will cause sidekiq to run the job instead of enqueuing it,
2. The user model email attribute must be called `email` or you can just replace the code above.
3. `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.map(&:to).flatten.count(user.email) == 1` check to see ActionMailer::Base.deliveries is delivering to user.email